# Splitting String after whitespace and then referencing it

Tags: java, arrays, regex, split, indexoutofboundsexception

The purpose of the program is to take the user input of his full name then break it down into his first name and last name(besides doing a few additional things).

It is supposed to split the String in half in between the whitespace, but I can only reference the first value of the split array, otherwise I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at FirstNameLastName.main(FirstNameLastName.java:41)
```

Here is the current code, any help would be appreciated:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FirstNameLastName {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        String fullName; //the users full name as he enters it          
        String fname; //the users first name
        int fnameCount; //number of characters in fname
        String lname; //the users last name;
        int lnameCount; // counts amount of characters in lname
        String init; //initials of the user, combination of first and last name

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input your first and last name with a space inbetween them");
        fullName = input.next();

        String[] parts = fullName.split("\\s+"); // creates an array within which the two split String values are stored
        fname = parts [0];  
        lname = parts [1];      
        fnameCount = fname.length();
        lnameCount = lname.length();

        System.out.println(fname);
        System.out.println(lname);      
        System.out.printf("Your first name is %s , which has %d characters" , fname , fnameChar);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("Your last name is %s , which has %d characters" , lname , lnameChar);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("Your initials are %c%c", fname.charAt(0),lname.charAt(0));

    }
}
```

Comment: if you check parts.length, what do you get?

Comment: It clearly tells that the array has only 1 element, how are you passing the input to this program. e.g. "FirstName LastName" or FirstName LastName

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is

```
fullName = input.next();
```

which reads only a single word.  You want it to be

```
fullName = input.nextLine();
```

which will read an entire line.

Comment: Oh. Yeah that fixed it. I assumed next included the whole line. I'll keep that in mind for future reference, thanks.